# How can I get the assembly version as a integer in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I can get it as a string:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version()
```

How can I convert this number to an int?

---

#### Example input:

> 8.0.0.1

#### Expected output:

> 8001

Comment: first step - what is the string that you get?

Comment: It's actually a multipart value.  You should see something like 1.0.3.4.  How that is displayed as an integer is pretty arbitrary

Comment: You have to ask yourself do you want the major or the minor version?

Comment: that's what I was thinking, I was intending to walk the questioner through to the conclusion

Comment: How do you propose to convert A.B.C.D into an integer hypothetically?

Comment: I just want to concatenate all the numbers in the string.

Comment: think of the cases 8.1.11.0 and 8.11.1.0

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Version comparison? There's a builtin way in the Version class.

Comment: As Adam sais, you're getting in serious trouble for every number > 9.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really have to do this conversion, you should at least reserve **an adequate amount of digits** for every version part.

Two digits for Major, Minor and Revision and four for Build:

```
var version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version();

Debug.Assert(version.Major >= 0 && version.Major < 100)
Debug.Assert(version.Minor >= 0 && version.Minor < 100)
Debug.Assert(version.Build >= 0 && version.Build < 10000)
Debug.Assert(version.Revision >= 0 && version.Revision < 100)

long longVersion = version.Major * 100000000L + 
                   version.Minor * 1000000L + 
                   version.Build * 100L + 
                   version.Revision;

int intVersion  = (int) longVersion;

Debug.Assert((long)intVersion == longVersion)
```

*Note that this method will still fail for some exotic versions!*

Don't even think about version 21.47.4836.48 :)

**EDIT:** Added assertions.

Comment: +1 for using Major/Minor/Build/Revision properties rather than parsing the version string.  As you point out it can fail (including overflowing) for large numbers.

Answer (score 3):

They are numbers, so you could just convert them to strings and stack them after each other:

```
Version v = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
string compacted = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", v.Major, v.Minor, v.Build, v.Revision);
int compactInt = int.Parse(compacted);
```

This of course only works well as long as each component is less than ten. After that you can't determine what the actual version is. The string "12345" can be 1.23.4.5 or 12.3.4.5 or 1.2.34.5 or...

If you know that they are all below ten, you could do it numerically:

```
Version v = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
int compactInt = v.Major * 1000 + v.Minor * 100 + v.Build * 10 + v.Revision;
```

If you don't know that, it gets a bit more complicated, but you can still do it without creating a string and parse it. It would be a bit faster, but it's 10 - 20 lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to treat it like a 4 byte integer.  You will be limited to the values of 0-255 for each of the version parts (major, minor, build, revision), but you can pack the version into an integer value.

This prevents the problem of 8.10.0.0 being greater than 9.0.0.0 (81,000 > 9,000).

```
    /// <summary>
    ///  
    /// Converts a version string in the format of 
    /// [major].[minor].[build].[revision] into an integer.
    ///  
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Each part of the build number must be within the range of 0 to 255.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="version"> The version to convert to an integer. </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The integer representation of the <paramref name="version"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public static int VersionToInt( string version ) {
        // Parse version number
        var versionParts = version.Split( '.' );
        if ( versionParts.Length != 4 ) {
            throw new ArgumentException( "Invalid version number; invalid number of version parts, expected 4 (major.minor.build.revision)",
                                         "version" );
        }

        // Convert parts to bytes
        byte major, minor, build, revision;
        if ( !byte.TryParse( versionParts[0], out major ) ) {
            throw new ArgumentException( "Invalid version number; invalid major number", 
                                         "version" );
        }
        if ( !byte.TryParse( versionParts[1], out minor ) ) {
            throw new ArgumentException( "Invalid version number; invalid minor number",
                                         "version" );
        }
        if ( !byte.TryParse( versionParts[2], out build ) ) {
            throw new ArgumentException( "Invalid version number; invalid build number", 
                                         "version" );
        }
        if ( !byte.TryParse( versionParts[3], out revision ) ) {
            throw new ArgumentException( "Invalid version number; invalid revision number", 
                                         "version" );
        }

        // Combine bytes into an integer
        var versionInteger = 0;
        versionInteger |= major << 24;
        versionInteger |= minor << 16;
        versionInteger |= build << 8;
        versionInteger |= revision;

        return versionInteger;
    }
```

Comment: This is **incredibly** helpful when dealing with VSTS Version Numbers and [Android VersionCodes](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html) which are integer-based and cannot exceed 2100000000.  All other examples just use the 4th version part - but this is no good for Android if you have an ALM branching strategy!

Answer (score 1):

You could string.Split('.'), iterate and int.parse()

Comment: +1 for splitting. This'll let you format the end result however you want, since you seem particular on how the final integer should look.

Answer (score 1):

The following 'works':

```
string version = "8.0.0.1";
int versionNumber = int.Parse(version.Replace(".", ""));
```

However, there would be no difference between version 8.0.11.0 and 8.0.1.10!

Comment: thanks that works, I just realized that I need in terms of minor major... I basically need  if it s 8.0.1.0 be converted to 801000

Comment: something like that? 
string version = "9.0.1.0";
int versionNumber = int.Parse(version+"0.0".Replace(".", ""));

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this:

```
Integer.Parse(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version().ToString().Replace(".", ""))
```

I stand Corrected.

Comment: You can't cast a string to an int. You have to parse it. Int.Parse or Convert.ToInt32 can do that.

Comment: You can't just strip out the "." characters because for example (as AdamRalph and probably others pointed out) stripping the periods out of version 8.1.11.0  and version 8.11.1.0 will both result in the same integer value: 81110

Answer (score 0):

You could also run into the situation where an assembly has a version of 0.0.1.1 and then the version looks like: 11. Definitely not desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Version v = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
long s = long.Parse(v.Major.ToString("0000") + v.MajorRevision.ToString("0000") + v.Minor.ToString("0000") + v.MinorRevision.ToString("0000"));
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem you're trying to solve?  Are you checking to see if the running version of some library is greater than or equal to some known bug-free version?  If so, the right thing to do is not to treat a .-delimited string of numbers as a single number, but to compare them individually to your target.

Comment: In that case you can just compare the Version objects. The comparison operators are overloaded to handle Version objects.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than that approach, and assuming that each of your version string elements is less than 255, you could just take each element as a byte in a 32 bit unsigned integer. This would not be very human readable, but would ensure that if V1 < V2 in version comparison then f(V1) < f(V2) for the integer conversion f.

Comment: The Build is 4 digits in most cases.

Comment: In which case, we could pull a couple of bits from major/minor to extend the build range to 2^14 odd.

Answer (score 0):

```
// assuming v is Version
var versionNumber = long.Parse(v.Major.ToString("x2") + v.Minor.ToString("x2") + v.Build.ToString("x2"), Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```